# kafka s3 confluent connector - upload json as string

Tags: json, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the kafka s3 sink connector from confluent to send json to s3.

Each entry from kafka is a valid json but when I get the data in s3 json file I have a string lookiin like this:

```
"{\"one\":\"test\"}\n\n{\"two\":\"none\"}"
```

Here is my current configuration:

```
name=s3-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
tasks.max=1000
rotate.schedule.interval.ms=60000
topics=MYTOPIC
flush.size=1
s3.bucket.name=BUCKETNAME
s3.region=us-east-1
aws.access.key.id=MYSUPERSECRETID
aws.secret.access.key=MYSUPERSECRETSECRET
s3.part.size=5242880
#value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
#value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
#key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
#keys.format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
schema.compatibility=NONE
timezone=UTC
locale=en-US
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
partition.duration.ms=86400000
path.format=YYYY/MM/dd/
```

My current issue is that I can't use those json for other treatment like that.

The commented parts in the configuration are options are tried to change the resulting string in the json to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`format.class`](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/index.html#s3-object-formats) describes how the connector will serialise the data into S3. It looks like your JSON is being serialised as a JSON object.

If you want an exact replica of the data in the topic then use

```
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.bytearray.ByteArrayFormat
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```

Comment: Nice, I get a valid json now, would you happen to know if it could generate json files in place of bin files?

Comment: @night-gold The extension is only controlled by the `format.class`. You'd use `JsonFormat` if you want `.json` files